# Google Sheets App Script If Else Function

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Create a function named validateHours().
The function has a single parameter named reference.
The function should examine the value of parameter named reference.This function should return Valid if reference is between 0 and 24 inclusive, otherwise it should return Invalid.
Return to the sheet and enter your new formula into cell B2.
Copy the formula and paste into B3:B6.
Each of the cells in column B should now show the values Valid or Invalid.

```
function validateHours(reference) {
  let result; 
  if (reference => 0 && reference <= 24) {
    result = "Valid";
  } else {
    result = "Invalid";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparison is wrong for the first part of your OR

```
function validateHours(reference) {
  let result; 
  if (reference >= 0 && reference <= 24) {
    result = "Valid";
  } else {
    result = "Invalid";
  }
  return result;
}
```

The above shows greater than or equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operator is wrong. It **should be** reference >= 0 **not** reference => 0.